# Accessing the listbox object and using it as a string globally in my class

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2008

I would like to use the selected item in my listbox as a string. From within listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged It works fine. How can I use it globally in 
my class?

I have it at the top of my class and have tried to make it static but I get 
the below error. Could someone show me how to reference it please?

> Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property

```
public class
{
static string listme = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Shown += new EventHandler(listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);

        }
public void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
           string items = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);

           MessageBox.Show(Backups + @"\" + items);


        }
```

Comment: Change it to `string listme =listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);` And if you need to use it just inside your Class, you don't need it to be static, as it wont recalculate its value.

Comment: @Bolu Your input is an answer not a comment and looks good to me too. Why not posting it as an answer?

Comment: Apoligize i should know. Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class
{
static string listme;

public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Shown += new EventHandler(listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);

        }
public void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            listme = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);

            MessageBox.Show(Backups + @"\" + listme);


        }
```

If you need to use it just inside your Class, you don't need it to be static, as it wont recalculate its value. And there are some code inside the question I can't understand. e.g. `listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;` first line inside `SelectedIndexChanged`... which I suppose this is to give a default value when the from is `shown` for your debugging, but if you leave it there, it will prevent user to change the selection....